# how to get value from json array in swift4

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone

I can't getting json value into variable.I'm printing value but the problem is I can't getting json value without array

here is my json

```
{
"Categories": [
    "city",
    "delhi"
   ]
}
```

I want to categories value with array im printing value with array

here is my code

```
do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
            print(json as AnyObject)

            if let Categories = json["Categories"] {
                print(Categories)
            }
```

Comment: try using swiftyjson via pods

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
 do {

     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:[String]]
      let arr1 = json["Categories"]!
      let str1 =  arr1.joined(separator: ":")
       print(str1)
     // or 
      let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
       let str =  decoded.categories.joined(separator: ":")
       print(str)

 } catch {
     print(error)
 }
```

or use

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let categories: [String] 
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case categories = "Categories"
    }
}
```

Comment: its printing with array i want to display without array

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier with `Codable`. First create custom model for your response

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    let categories: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case categories = "Categories"
    }
}
```

Then decode your `data` which your receive using `JSONDecoder`

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        let string = decoded.categories.joined(separator: ", ") // if u need to join 
                                                                // your array to 
                                                                // single `String`
        print(string)
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

Comment: its getting without array but i want to that value into variable

Answer (score 0):

Use built in swift support for decoding json by conforming to `Decodable` and also conform to `CustomStringConvertible` to get a string representation of the values

```
struct Item: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let categories: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case categories = "Categories"
    }

    public var description: String {
        return categories.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: data)
    let descr = result.description
    print(descr)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Model Class should be like this
struct JsonResposne : Codable {

    let categories : [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case categories = "Categories"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            categories = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .categories)
    }

}

func getCategoriesResponse() {

Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if response.data != nil {
                do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let apiResponse:JsonResponse = try decoder.decode(JsonResponse.self, from: responseData)
        print(apiResponse.categories.count)

    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
                }
            }
            break
        case .failure:
            print("There was something with your call")
            break
        }
    }
```

}